# Google Play Store API Level requirement minimum vs target

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Google communicated that in order to publish a new app or an app update in the Play store, you must meet Google Play’s NEW target API level requirements:

Starting in August 2022, new apps must target API level 31 (Android 12) or above.
Starting in November 2022, app updates must target API level 31 (Android 12) or above.

My current gradle build target:

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 33
```

However, as you can see my minSdkVersion targets a lower version. Do I have to upgrade the MIN SDK VERSION along with the TARGET version? Or can I still leave it as lower as posible for maximum compatibility with older devices?

Comment: *must target* ... there is no words about minSdkVersion

Comment: Not sure if it's a fit question for this site, but yes, the requirement is only about the targetSdkVersion; it's normal and expected that you support older versions, and minSdkVersion can be as low as you are able to support.

Answer (score 7):

It is April 2023 now (way after Google's `August 2022` deadline) and my apps pass all reviews with:

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 33
```

So, answering your questions:

1. No, you do not have to upgrade the minSdkVersion along with the TARGET version
2. Yes, you can I still leave it as lower as possible for maximum compatibility with older devices.

Answer (score 4):

If this helps anyone... I was having the same issue and warnings, and Google was pointing to old versions I had paused in closed testing. Once I simply unselected the testers on those versions, I received a message that all issues had been resolved.

Comment: This helped me out, thank you! Had an older version in closed testing... same thing seems to apply for open testing tracks too.

Answer (score 2):

Even after upgrading `targetSdkVersion` to 34 I was still getting this warning on my Android device. What got rid of was upgrading `minSdkVersion` to 26 as well.